# Random Matrix Product

Tags: matrices, random

Suppose I have the random matrix $G \in R^{d \times d}$. I draw each element in $G$ independently from a Gaussian with Zero mean and finite variance.

What can I say about the product of $GG^T$? Specialy how are Off-Diagonal values compared to diagonal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Definition

Comment: The marginal distribution of Matrix Elements is exactly what I want. But how does ist look like in higher dimensions?